# How do I email exception and then return original message to Camel route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route that validates a bean. If validation fails, I want to email the validation exception and then continue processing the bean. Here's what I have so far:

```
onException(BeanValidationException.class)
     // the body is an instance of MyClass
    .setBody(simple("${exception}")) 
     // Now it's a String representation of the exception.
    .to("{{route.mail}}")
    .continued(true); //now what? how do I get back the instance of MyClass?
    
    from("{{route.from}}")
    .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(MyClass.class))
    .to("bean-validator:priceFeedValidator")
    //continued processing of bean
```

When validation fails, the above code send the email validation exception. That's good. But when it continues processing the bean, it fails because the message body is no longer a MyClass bean but the exception string.

How can I return back the bean that was there before I called setBody?

Alternatively, is there a way to send the exception in email without overwriting the body of the original flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can store the body in a temporary exchange property before change it to the exception message when sending the email and restore it afterwards.

A related question
[Camel Body: body1 -> body2 -> body1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75816612/camel-body-body1-body2-body1)

You can also use a bean/processor to send the email, and write a bit of Java code that grab the *caused exception* from the validation exception, and build the email to send (via a producer template etc) and then avoid changing the message body in the Camel route.