# Camel Body: body1 -> body2 -> body1?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a message body. Then, I change it. Then, I want to reset it back to the original message body:

```
from("{{route:from}}") // step 1
.setBody("hello world") // step 2
.setBody(/*set body back to value produced by step 1*/);
```

How do I reset the body back to the value produced by step 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the body to an exchange property before the first time you change the body, and then restore it afterwards. You can also look at the claim check EIP that has push/pop actions for such behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to use .`setProperty("temp", simple("${body}"))` in between step 1 & 2 and then call `.setBody(simple("${properties:temp}"))` after step 2. This works but only in the case the body is a string. Doesn't seem to work for other types. I get `org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type`. Claim check works well.